# Iphone Simulator photos Without changing orientation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I've followed several posts about adding photos to the iPhone Simulator and they all work,
however, there is a bad side effect of changing the Orientation and the related TIFF metadata.
This is in conflict with the iPhone itself.

For example, regardless of the orientation you take the photo (Portrait/Landscape), the iPhone will display it "right-side up". However, the metadata remains unchanged, so the Orientation information is still correct (i.e. 0,1,2, or 3)

However, once added to the iPhone Simulator, the images are "corrected" and the Orientation is always "0".

This means that these statements work on the iPhone (correctly returns 0-3) but not on the Simulator (always returns 0):

```
UIImage *image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSLog(@"original orientation:%li",image.imageOrientation);
```

So, here is my question (finally):

How can I add photos to the Simulator and maintain the correct, and necessary, metadata so that I can test without having to use my iPhone?

Comment: Simulator is pretty notoriously crappy when it comes to photos. I know you're looking to avoid a physical device, but I would recommend against using the simulator.

Comment: Bottom line... you can't develop without testing on several physical devices.  The simulator is just that, a simulator.  It's kind of close, but there are numerous differences.

Comment: The simulator may indeed be only partially useful, but my question is still unanswered - is there a way to manage photos in the Simulator so that it matches the iPhone? Specifically, the metadata for orientation?